# FullCalendar check if resize is from Start or End

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I need to detect if resize is starting from the START (left) or from the END (right).

I tried this solution but didn't work [FullCalendar: Detect if resize was on Start or on End.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181703/fullcalendar-detect-if-resize-was-on-start-or-on-end)

I need to implement this code. Basically now It works if I resize an event from END, but not if I change from START cause i can't detect if I change from START or END.

```
events: [
            { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T02:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', title: 'Carico su camion', id_eventi_prima: "", id_eventi_dopo: "2,3,4,5,6,7", id_evento_collegato: "2,3,4,5,6,7", backgroundColor: "green" },
            { id: '2', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T13:00:00', title: 'Viaggio', id_eventi_prima: "1", id_eventi_dopo: "3,4,5,6,7", id_evento_collegato: "1,3,4,5,6,7", backgroundColor: "red" },
            { id: '3', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T13:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T15:00:00', title: 'Scarico', id_eventi_prima: "1,2", id_eventi_dopo: "4,5,6,7", id_evento_collegato: "1,2,4,5,6,7", backgroundColor: "grey", editable: false },
            { id: '4', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T15:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T19:00:00', title: 'Produzione', id_eventi_prima: "1,2,3", id_eventi_dopo: "5,6,7", id_evento_collegato: "1,2,3,5,6,7", backgroundColor: "orange" },
            { id: '5', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T19:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T21:00:00', title: 'Pulizia impianto', id_eventi_prima: "1,2,3,4", id_eventi_dopo: "6,7", id_evento_collegato: "1,2,3,4,6,7", backgroundColor: "blue" },
            { id: '6', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T21:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T22:00:00', title: 'Smontaggio', id_eventi_prima: "1,2,3,4,5", id_eventi_dopo: "7", id_evento_collegato: "1,2,3,4,5,7",  backgroundColor: "green" },
            { id: '7', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T22:00:00', end: '2017-09-08T06:00:00', title: 'Ritorno in azienda', id_eventi_prima: "1,2,3,4,5,6", id_eventi_dopo: "", id_evento_collegato: "1,2,3,4,5,6", backgroundColor: "pink" },
            { id: '8', resourceId: 'b', start: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T06:00:00', title: 'Viaggio', id_eventi_prima: "", id_eventi_dopo: "", id_evento_collegato: "", backgroundColor: "green" }
        ],
        eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
            var arrayEventiCollegati = event.id_evento_collegato;
            var newResourceId = event.resourceId;
            var relatedEvents = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents", function(evt) {
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayEventiCollegati.length; i++)
                {
                    if (evt.id == arrayEventiCollegati[i]) return true;
                }

                return false;
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < relatedEvents.length; i++)
            {
                relatedEvents[i].resourceId = newResourceId;
                relatedEvents[i].start.add(delta);
                relatedEvents[i].end.add(delta);
            }

            $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvents", relatedEvents);
        }, //eventDrop
        eventResize: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
            var id_eventi_prima = event.id_eventi_prima;
            var id_eventi_dopo = event.id_eventi_dopo;

            var arrayEventiCollegati = event.id_evento_collegato;
            var relatedEvents = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents", function(evt) {
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayEventiCollegati.length; i++)
                {
                    if ( evt.id == arrayEventiCollegati[i] ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < relatedEvents.length; i++)
            {
                for (var k = 0; k < id_eventi_dopo.length; k++) {
                            if ( relatedEvents[i].id == id_eventi_dopo[k] ) {
                relatedEvents[i].start.add(delta);
                relatedEvents[i].end.add(delta);
                            }
                }
            }

            $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvents", relatedEvents);
        } //eventResize
```

Comment: why do you need to know?

Comment: I need it to implement my project here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539993/drag-drop-group-of-events-connected-together-in-fullcalendar/46542654  .Basically if I resize from END in a event in the middle of others events (example events in order ID = 1,2,3,4) If resize event 2 at the END, then event 1 still remain unchanged and events 3,4 get new position. Otherwise if i change event 2 from START, then event get new position, and events 3,4 unchanged.

Comment: I uploaded my code partially working only from END. For your understanding, "id_eventi_prima" in english = "id_events_before" and "id_eventi_dopo" = "id_events_after"